# How to convert test / nclob / varchar to hex with SQL in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, text, hex, hana, varchar

How do I convert text to hex using SQL in SAP HANA?

(I want to be able to read also nonprintable characters
(new line, linefeed, etc.)
since we have an issue with the text)

Answer (score 0):

Use `cast(cdata as varbinary)`

Test SQL:

```
SELECT cast ('Jtext' as varbinary) from dummy;
```

Output:

```
4A74657874
```

4A = J
74 = t
...